# Reauthentication failed error while accessing bigquery via python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

i am trying to access  bigquery using python . even though after executing "gcloud auth login"
getting  below error.

google.auth.exceptions.ReauthFailError: Reauthentication failed. Reauthentication challenge could not be answered because you are not in an interactive session.

what can be issue here

Comment: Can you follow this [tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-bigquery-python#0) to access BigQuery using python? Also, could you clarify more on your use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this problem by creating a service account and set up the Cloud SDK to use the service account.

**Example command:**

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account account-name --key-file=/fullpath/service-account.json
```

Other way is to set up the environment variables for the Python script to use while accessing BigQuery.

**Example command:**

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/fullpath/service-account.json
```